# How to add relationship on same fields of Two tables (Table Order and Table Product) in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, database-relations, table-relationships

Dear anyone can help me as i have two tables named as Order and Products which have more than two multiple same fields i want to make relationship among all same fields in both tables
You can see tables in pictures below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields. And you don't _make relationships_, they are already there. (But you can create foreign keys for them.)

Comment: The only relationship between the 2 tables should be `product_id`. Remove the `product_name` from the `Orders` table. This is not a normalized structure now.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple, assuming `product_id` is a key for items.

Make the column `Order.product_id` be a `FOREIGN KEY` to `Product.product_id`.
Drop all other columns that exist in `Products` from the table `Order`.

Note inspired by comment from @WEI_DBA: `price` and `quantity` are not really characteristics of `product`, but of `order`. These should remain in the `Order` table and be removed from the `Product` table instead. Generally, give each table the data which depend on that table's primary key.

Comment: I would keep `product_price` and `product_quantity` on the `Orders` table. The price can change over time and you want to keep that history in your `Orders` table.